# How to separate lines depending on the value in column 1

Tags: shell

I have a text file that contains the following (a b c d etc... contains some random values):

```
 1 a
 1 b
 2 c
 2 d
 2 e
 2 f
 6 g
 6 h
 6 i
12 j
12 k
```

Is there a way to separate lines with some characters depending on the content of the first string, knowing that those numbers will always be increasing, but may vary as well. The separation would be when first string is incrementing, going from 1 to 2, then 2 to 6 etc...

The output would be like this (here I would like to use ---------- as a separation):

```
1 a
1 b
----------
2 c
2 d
2 e
2 f
----------
6 g
6 h
6 i
----------
12 j
12 k
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'NR>1 && old != $1 { print "----------" } { print; old = $1 }'
```

If it isn't the first line and the value in `old` isn't the same as in `$1`, print the separator.  Then unconditionally print the current line, and record the value of `$1` in `old` so that we remember for next time.  Repeat until done.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly, that is a really nice one :) thank you for this command.